# twig: Overriding blocks defined in embed tag

Tags: twig

Is there a way to override blocks defined inside and `embed` tag inside the parent template in a child template.e.g: I have three templates: `a`, `b` and `c`. `a` embeds `b` and `c` extends `a`.

```
{# a.html.twig #}
{% embed b.html.twig %}
  {% block content %}
    laksjflkj
    {% block placeholder %}
    I want to override this template in c, it is actually defined here and has nothing to do with b
    {% endblock placeholder %}
  {% endblock content %}
{% endembed %}
```

---

```
{# b.html.twig #}
{% block content %}
  blahblah
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{# c.html.twig #}
{% extends 'a.html.twig' %}
  {% block placeholder %}
    let's override the block defined inside a
  {% endblock placeholder %}
```

How do I override the `placeholder` block inside `c.html.twig`?

Comment: To have hints, you can look at the twig's compiled code (small link below the context) http://twigfiddle.com/jb63tv - should be related to inheritance order and scopes. I don't have the time to look at it right now but that's a good question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new file called `d.html.twig`, which extends `c.html.twig` and override your `placeholder` block like this :

```
{# d.html.twig #}
{% extends 'c.html.twig' %}
  {% block placeholder %}
    Overrided !
  {% endblock placeholder %}
```

Comment: I didn't. This is a nice work-around but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question is asking how to override blocks in an embedded template **directly** in the embedding template. Your solution doesn't solve that specific problem, but it solves the underlying problem.

Comment: @user2268997 there is no solution to your specific problem, it's impossible.